# Extract only digits and full stop from string

Tags: r

I have following strings :
`x <- c("3 333.33!", "1 002 22??", "232.23x")`
I only want to keep numbers and dots.

is there a solution?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

We could just extract any digits and full stops and then collapse the string again.

```r
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(x, "[:digit:]|\\."), function(x) str_c(x, collapse=""))

"3333.33" "100222"  "232.23"
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove whitespace (regex `" +"` means "one or more spaces") and then call `readr::parse_number()`, which ignores alphabetic characters/punctuation other than `.-`

```r
x |> stringr::str_remove(" +") |> readr::parse_number()
```

Comment: "thank-you" comments, while appreciated, are [deprecated on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged).  You are encouraged to (1) upvote (if you have the reputation) and (2) click the check-mark to accept the solution that **best** answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

in base R:

```
gsub("[^0-9.]", "", x)
[1] "3333.33" "100222"  "232.23"
```

if you need them as numeric:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", x))
[1]   3333.33 100222.00    232.23
```